# How to convert css background url to embeded html url?

Tags: html, css, linux, http, web

For example, a.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="a.css">
```

a.css

```
.bg {
    width: 100%;
    background: url(/a.gif) bottom repeat-x;
}
```

The browser will get `a.html` first, then `a.css`, then `a.gif`.

Is there anyway to put `a.gif` in html so the browser can request `a.css` and `a.gif` at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the prefetch tag, like this in your `<head>`:

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="/a.gif">
```